# Flatlist, how do I add iterable index

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I add a iterable index to my flatlist? In my `SummaryCard` component, I need to fire a function that tracks which `SummaryCard` is clicked, for example, "Summary Card vehicle 1 clicked", "summary vehicle 2 clicked".

```
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <SummaryCard vehicle={item} key={item.vehicleId} />
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.vehicleId.toString()}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the `index` argument inside the [`renderItem`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem) callback function.

But indexes can eventually change if the list changes the size or content. As a solution to that you could consider tracking your clicked elements by `id` instead (or `vehicleId`). You can create some logic like this:

```
const [selectedVehicles, setSelectedVehicles] = useState([]);

const toggleSelectVehicle = (vehicleId) => {
  setSelectedVehicles((previousIds) => {
    if (previousIds.includes(vehicleId)) {
      return [...previousIds.filter((id) => id === vehicleId)];
    }

    return [...previousIds, vehicleId];
  })
}

return (
 <FlatList
    data={data}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <SummaryCard
        vehicle={item}
        key={item.vehicleId}
        selected={selectedVehicles.includes(item.vehicleId)}
        onClick={() => toggleSelectVehicle(item.vehicleId)}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.vehicleId.toString()}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data can be modified to have an index property. You can do this just after receiving the data.

```
const indexedData= data.map((item, index) => ({
...item,
index,
}));
```

Then you can modify your Flatlist component to use the modified data and can access the card number by `item.index`.

```
 <FlatList
data={indexedData}
contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
renderItem={({ item }) => (
  <SummaryCard vehicle={item} key={item.vehicleId} />
)}
keyExtractor={(item) => item.vehicleId.toString()}
ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[renderItem](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem) takes an object with three possible properties:

1. `item` (Object): The item from `data` being rendered.
2. `index` (number): The index corresponding to this item in the `data` array.
3. `separators` (Object)

   - `highlight` (Function)
   - `unhighlight` (Function)
   - `updateProps` (Function)

     - `select` (enum('leading', 'trailing'))
     - `newProps` (Object)

So you could write some code like this

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <SummaryCard vehicle={item} vehicleIndex={index} key={item.vehicleId} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.vehicleId.toString()}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument from `renderItem` is the index of the data passed to the FlatList.

You simply need to do:

```js
<FlatList
  data={data}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
  {/* Get index as second argument, and subsequently pass to SummaryCard */
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <SummaryCard vehicle={item} index={index} key={item.vehicleId} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.vehicleId.toString()}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
/>
```